# Tool for drawing timing diagrams

Tags: hardware, verilog, asic, timing-diagram

Recently I am working with a hardware design group developing an [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit). And I am drawing a lot of timing diagrams for which I am using Microsoft Excel, as it is easy to import into Word document. But, things are getting more and more difficult with Excel.

What can be used to draw timing diagrams? Is there any easy tool out there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the same problem and tried the following tools:

- drawtiming
- timing ([LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX))
- tikz-timing (LaTeX)
- [Microsoft Visio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio)

After trying all these I now ended up using Visio and pen&pencil. All other programs lacked support for adding arrows/relationships between signals easily. In Visio, such things are absolutely easy. And you can export the diagrams directly to [PowerPoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint) or even as [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) for using them in LaTeX.

Comment: I just checked out drawtiming, thanks for the tip! It seems a nice neat package, a bit like graphviz for timing diagrams.  It'll do arrows now too by the looks of things!

  I once tried to get the Latex things going, but since I don't have admin permissions on my work computer, I'd difficulty installing the modules.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Visio tip. I am a moron not to try visio in the first place. I also checked out Drawtiming, it is kind of neat.

Comment: For Visio, make sure you use the "real" (desktop) version of Visio, not the web-based Office 365 version. The web-based version is a joke (you can't even connect lines together). Powerpoint is has more powerful drawing features than web Visio.

Answer (score 28):

[WaveDrom](http://wavedrom.com/) is a free and open source online digital timing diagram rendering engine that uses [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) to convert WaveJSON input text description into SVG vector graphics.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words: http://wavedrom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor.html
A pefect tool to combine with RestructuredText/Sphinx

Comment: Except when the picture doesn't exist. ;)
Possible to relink this?

Comment: Wow I was looking for one of these for long long time.... thanks bro

Answer (score 10):

If you like LaTeX and don't mind the extra steps to get the generated image into Word (on which I guess you depend), [tikz-timing](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/) is very nice. I find it very easy to use and the diagrams look very good!

Apart from that, the companies I worked in so far used Visio for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 7):

The post *[Re: Visio Timing Diagram](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Visio/microsoft.public.visio.developer/2004-08/0002.html)* has a link to a [Visio stencil](http://www.mvps.org/visio/FTP/TIMEDIA.VSS).

Answer (score 5):

[drawtiming](http://drawtiming.sourceforge.net/samples.html) looks interesting.

Answer (score 5):

[Timing Designer](http://www.timingdesigner.com) and [Timing Diagrammer](http://www.syncad.com/timing_diagrammer_timing_diagram_editor.htm) are the two main commercial programs.  They are similar in functions and user interface.  Both have OLE and other export capability.

Comment: The good ones are very expensive.  I've never seen a free one that was worth using.  Visio or OpenOffice Draw are your best bet.  I know my company has created special Visio stencils for doing waveforms (sorry, I can't share them).  It's still a pain that way but it's not intolerable.

Answer (score 3):

I find it necessary to add [TimingAnalyzer](https://www.timing-diagrams.com/) to the mix.  It is only in Beta but at least he is actively developing it.  ~T

Answer (score 3):

WaveDrom tool, mentioned above, moved to GitHub [wavedrom.com](http://wavedrom.com).

Answer (score 3):

Waveme http://waveme.weebly.com/

I just released a new free GUI-based timing diagram drawing tool for Windows (and Linux/MacOS via Wine).

It draws digital waveforms (signals and buses) with gaps, arrows and labels, and is highly customizable.

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with simpler waveforms on a regular grid, you can quickly create something with [Timing Font](http://www.pcserviceselectronics.co.uk/fonts/) or XWave (linked from the first link). Another option would be
Gnome Dia, a simple vector drawing program.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago we used [IGOR](http://www.wavemetrics.com/index.html) for all kinds of measurement data visualization. But it's not for free, if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I use an online spreadsheet like Google Docs or Excel for timing diagrams - by making all cells equal width and height and play with the borders of the cell. This is great quick way to explain simple concepts especially during collaborative (online) work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Timing Designer](http://www.ema-eda.com/Products/EMADesignAutomation/TimingDesigner.aspx) and [Waveformer](http://www.syncad.com/waveformer_waveform_editor.htm). They can read basic [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) files. Waveformer has a decent demo version for Windows. You can't save designs, but you can screen capture them. For very basic timing diagrams, I've used the Visio templates mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Free Online Digital Diagram Generator" to draw the diagram then copy and past the screen in to your documents. If you want to try a tool that do not need your login or email, and can save your editing for future use. You can try this javascript tool on google.
http://hardwarelanguages.blogspot.com/2016/08/free-online-digital-diagram-generator.html

Your digital waveform diagram is saved in the URL encrypted, no one else can see it until your share the links with email/skypee/facebook, and etc.